# Mapping between UML Diagrams and SDLC?

Tags: uml, sdlc

What are different UML diagrams that I can use at different stages of SDLC? I am looking for a mapping of possible UML diagrams to each of the different stages in SDLC.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to that, depending on your SDLC methodology. I would recommend you to look at the Unified Process, which is free methodology created by the autohors of UML, so it should best reflect at what are those different diagrams best.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/modelingTechniques.htm
This site may help you.There is lot of details about uml diagrams and the scope where they are used in software development steps along with some reference books.

Answer (score 0):

Activity diagrams: Used to model business processes.

Object diagrams: Is a collection of objects - a snapshot of a system at an instance in time.

Class diagrams: Describes all possible objects of a given type.

Sequence diagrams/Communication diagrams: Known collectively as interaction diagrams. These can be used to aid dynamic modelling showing how objects interact.

State diagrams: Shows how a model changes from state to state.

Use case diagrams: Used to record and communicate your understanding of the use case view of a system, and later to plan iterations and validate software systems.

I've probably missed a few.

BTW a free tool that is used by a number of universities is UMLet http://www.umlet.com/, which is really simple and easy to use.